# okhttp run on thread or coroutine on ktor applcation

Tags: okhttp, ktor

I'm using okhttp with ktor on my server application and run like this.

```
runBlocking {
    launch {
        okhttpClient.get(url)
    }
}
```

and this is logging result.

```
2021-05-17 11:18:21.620 DEBUG 11928 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/test/test2", parameters={}
2021-05-17 11:18:21.621 DEBUG 11928 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.example.kotlinstudy.TestController#test2()
2021-05-17 11:18:21.788 DEBUG 11928 --- [alhost:8081/...] okhttp3.internal.concurrent.TaskRunner   : Q10000 scheduled after   0 µs: OkHttp ConnectionPool
2021-05-17 11:18:21.789 DEBUG 11928 --- [Http TaskRunner] okhttp3.internal.concurrent.TaskRunner   : Q10000 starting              : OkHttp ConnectionPool
2021-05-17 11:18:21.789 DEBUG 11928 --- [ ConnectionPool] okhttp3.internal.concurrent.TaskRunner   : Q10000 run again after 300 s : OkHttp ConnectionPool
2021-05-17 11:18:21.789 DEBUG 11928 --- [Http TaskRunner] okhttp3.internal.concurrent.TaskRunner   : Q10000 finished run in 287 µs: OkHttp ConnectionPool
2021-05-17 11:18:21.828 DEBUG 11928 --- [@call-context#5] okhttp3.internal.concurrent.TaskRunner   : Q10000 scheduled after   0 µs: OkHttp ConnectionPool
2021-05-17 11:18:21.828 DEBUG 11928 --- [Http TaskRunner] okhttp3.internal.concurrent.TaskRunner   : Q10000 starting              : OkHttp ConnectionPool
2021-05-17 11:18:21.828 DEBUG 11928 --- [ ConnectionPool] okhttp3.internal.concurrent.TaskRunner   : Q10000 run again after 300 s : OkHttp ConnectionPool
2021-05-17 11:18:21.828 DEBUG 11928 --- [Http TaskRunner] okhttp3.internal.concurrent.TaskRunner   : Q10000 finished run in  92 µs: OkHttp ConnectionPool
2021-05-17 11:18:21.883 DEBUG 11928 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Using 'text/plain', given [*/*] and supported [text/plain, */*, text/plain, */*, application/json, application/*+json, application/json, application/*+json, application/json, application/*+json]
2021-05-17 11:18:21.883 DEBUG 11928 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Writing ["test1"]
2021-05-17 11:18:21.890 DEBUG 11928 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
```

It's started tomcat nio thread and running on okhttp thread.
you know coroutine is light thread. I expect that runBlocking code working on coroutine thread.
but it seem another thread.

So okhttpClent run on coroutine thread? or normal thread?
What should I do to work with coroutine thread?
Using CIO client?

Thanks all.

This is CIO calling log. It looks like working coroutine thread

```
2021-05-17 13:05:16.271 DEBUG 20068 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/test/test3", parameters={}
2021-05-17 13:05:16.273 DEBUG 20068 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.example.kotlinstudy.TestController#test3()
2021-05-17 13:05:16.306  INFO 20068 --- [-2 @coroutine#5] io.ktor.client.HttpClient                : REQUEST: http://localhost:8081/server1
2021-05-17 13:05:16.307  INFO 20068 --- [-2 @coroutine#5] io.ktor.client.HttpClient                : METHOD: HttpMethod(value=GET)
2021-05-17 13:05:16.307  INFO 20068 --- [-2 @coroutine#5] io.ktor.client.HttpClient                : COMMON HEADERS
2021-05-17 13:05:16.308  INFO 20068 --- [-2 @coroutine#5] io.ktor.client.HttpClient                : -> Accept: application/json
2021-05-17 13:05:16.309  INFO 20068 --- [-2 @coroutine#5] io.ktor.client.HttpClient                : -> Accept-Charset: UTF-8
2021-05-17 13:05:16.309  INFO 20068 --- [-2 @coroutine#5] io.ktor.client.HttpClient                : -> User-Agent: Ktor client/1.3.1(npay-point)
2021-05-17 13:05:16.309  INFO 20068 --- [-2 @coroutine#5] io.ktor.client.HttpClient                : CONTENT HEADERS
2021-05-17 13:05:16.309  INFO 20068 --- [-2 @coroutine#5] io.ktor.client.HttpClient                : -> Content-Length: 0
2021-05-17 13:05:16.423  INFO 20068 --- [-2 @coroutine#5] io.ktor.client.HttpClient                : RESPONSE: 200 OK
2021-05-17 13:05:16.423  INFO 20068 --- [-2 @coroutine#5] io.ktor.client.HttpClient                : METHOD: HttpMethod(value=GET)
2021-05-17 13:05:16.423  INFO 20068 --- [-2 @coroutine#5] io.ktor.client.HttpClient                : FROM: http://localhost:8081/server1
2021-05-17 13:05:16.423  INFO 20068 --- [-2 @coroutine#5] io.ktor.client.HttpClient                : COMMON HEADERS
2021-05-17 13:05:16.423  INFO 20068 --- [-2 @coroutine#5] io.ktor.client.HttpClient                : -> Content-Length: 20
2021-05-17 13:05:16.423  INFO 20068 --- [-2 @coroutine#5] io.ktor.client.HttpClient                : -> Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Hello world! server1
2021-05-17 13:05:16.467 DEBUG 20068 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Using 'text/plain', given [*/*] and supported [text/plain, */*, text/plain, */*, application/json, application/*+json, application/json, application/*+json, application/json, application/*+json]
2021-05-17 13:05:16.468 DEBUG 20068 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Writing ["test1"]
2021-05-17 13:05:16.475 DEBUG 20068 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though most people see coroutines as lightweight threads they are in fact not really that. A coroutine starts in a thread and then suspends until its ready to resume. See: [Coroutines basics](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-basics.html#your-first-coroutine):

`...a coroutine is not bound to any particular thread. It may suspend its execution in one thread and resume in another one.`

Coroutines are not designed to stick to one thread and only use that. You'll need to clarify the use case you need this for as it could be more of a code design decision.